# is there any python function which allows to cut text according to name of company?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp

I want to have the name of company in the text with the part of the text which is associated with the name of the company, please ...

```
text="""Facebook est spécialisé dans les services web, qui permet aux utilisateurs d'échanger par message. Elle est parmi les autres entreprises qui sont spécialisés dans le même domaine. Google est une entreprise aussi spécialisé dans les services informatiques"""

Company=["Facebook","Google","Apple"]

negative_patterns_list = [
    "\s[A-Z]",
    "\s[0-9]"
    ]
split_elements = [           
    "[.!?%$-] "
    ]

split_pattern = "(?<!%s)(%s)" % ("|".join(negative_patterns_list), "|".join(split_elements))

# séparation sur les éléments ponctuations de fin de phrases
text_splitted = re.split(split_pattern, text)
liste_split = [elt for idx, elt in enumerate(text_splitted) if idx % 2 == 0]
sentences = [elt for idx, elt in enumerate(liste_split) if elt != '']
```

this code allows to split text in sentences( 'sentences' is a list of sentences)

```
sentences : ["Facebook est spécialisé dans les services web, qui permet aux utilisateurs d'échanger 
par message",'Elle est parmi les autres entreprises qui sont spécialisés dans le même domaine',
'Google est une entreprise aussi spécialisé dans les services informatiques']
```

the first sentence contain "Facebook" : its ok , the 3rd sentence also contain Google its ok ...
but the second does not contain a name of company , so i want to concatenate it with the previous sentence in the list , i.e :

```
["Facebook est spécialisé dans les services web, qui permet aux utilisateurs d'échanger 
par message, Elle est parmi les autres entreprises qui sont spécialisés dans le même domaine",
"Google est une entreprise aussi spécialisé dans les services informatiques"]
```

As output, i want to have :

```
"Facebook" : "Facebook est spécialisé dans les services web, qui permet aux utilisateurs d'échanger 
par message, Elle est parmi les autres entreprises qui sont spécialisés dans le même domaine"

"Google" : "Google est une entreprise aussi spécialisé dans les services informatiques"
```

Comment: Do you want the sentence always with the previous one if one of the entity is not cited in it? Or it may go with the following? Wha's up with for example: `"Facebook is a company. There's another interesting company. I mean Google"`.

Comment: @Nja aaa yes yes it may go with the following i.e  output= `["Facebook is a company" , "There's another interesting company. I mean Google"]`

Comment: Which is the purpose of the job? Why do you want to associate sentences by company?

Comment: to do the topic modelling for each company 
for each company , we will have a sub-text , so we will apply topic modelling on this sub-text for each company

Comment: what interests me is to do this split correctly but I can't ..

Comment: mmm. I think i will start by coreference resolution, maybe using some resource like [StanfordNLP](https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/coref.shtml), I can't find a simple way to this with some heuristics.

Comment: how we can do this with StanfordNLP ? i am beginner and i don't know whats stanfordNLP... If you try it please , tell me know how ...

Comment: You should read their documentation. If you work in python start from this library [stanfordnlp/stanza](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/stanza)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
sentences = [elt for idx, elt in enumerate(liste_split) if elt != '']
```

The below brute force solution gets you what you are looking for given presented example. Note that the sentences are separated by punctuation (instead of comma as your result shows - this obv can be easily adjusted).

There are likely more optimal solutions if time complexity is a important factor (i.e. you are using v large data sets).

```
sentances = []
prev_comp = ""
sentences = {key: "" for key in Company}

for idx, sentance in enumerate(liste_split):
    found = False

    for iComp in Company:
        if iComp in sentance:
            found = True
            sentences[iComp] += ' ' + sentance + '.'
            prev_comp = iComp
    
    if not found:
        sentences[prev_comp] += ' ' + sentance + '.'
    elif prev_comp == "" and not found:
        raise NotImplementedError

for key, value in sentences.items():
    sentences[key] = value.lstrip(" ")
```